# Python: Close TCP client connection to server after no server message for x seconds

Tags: python, python-multithreading, tcpclient

I'm trying to create Python TCP client. It is fully functional, but I desire a functionality where if a "connected" message hasn't been recieved from the server for x seconds, then I can close my connection. I currently have a separate thread for recieving messages from the server. Basically, if I receive a message that says "connected" I want to reset a timer.

I've tried a few different approaches to solving it. I've tried to have a separate thread with a timer that keep track of when to disconnect using global variables which is a messy solution which didn't work regardless. I tried to make my own threading subclass but I still was not able to solve the problem and it introduced a lot more complexity than I really need.

a simple approach that I took was to try to have a timer in the while loop in my recieve function. This works for disconnecting from the server, but it will only timeout when a message is sent (due to the try block) and not actually the second the timer is up.

```py
import threading, time, sys

def main():
    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = sys.argv[2]

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    address = (host, port)
    sock.connect(address)

    rec_thread = threading.Thread(target=rec, args=(sock,))
    rec_thread.setDaemon(True)
    rec_thread.start()

    while True:
        message = input()
        sock.sendall(str.encode(message))

def rec(sock):
    start_time = time.time() 
    while True:

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        if(elapsed_time > 10):
            sock.close()

        try:
            msg = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf8")

            if msg == 'connected':
                start_time = time.time()
            else:
                print(msg)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sock.close()
            break
```

If I use this approach then I will only actually close the connection after I recieve a message from the server.

ex: I want it to disconnect immediately after 10s, but if I don't get any message from the server until 14s, then it won't disconnect until 14s.

Comment: how about [socket.settimeout(value)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)

Comment: This is just a case for a simple timeout. I can't reset it based on receiving my 'connect' message. If I did do socket.settimeout(value) I would have to compare it to my elapsed time and my code would be functionally the same.